# Error populating a kendo grid using Json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to fill a kendo grid from my controller, but my datasource has a entity class that can be null in some cases. Everything work well, except when my entity has a null value.

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Filter val)
>     {
>         List<Incidencia> vObj = _casosService.GetDatos();
>
>         if (null != val.Desc && val.Desc.Length > 0)
>             vObj = vObj.Where(o =>
>                     o.Description.ToLower().Contains(val.Desc.ToLower()) ||
>                     o.Tittle.ToLower().Contains(val.Desc.ToLower())                       
>
>                 .ToList();
>
>         return Json(vObj.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
>            {
>                o.Id,
>                o.EventDate,
>                o.Description,
>                o.System.shortName,
>                o.Tittle,
>                o.IdUserReport,
>                o.Close,
>                o.CloseDate,
>                o.Customers.ShortName // <-- Throw an exception if has a null value.
>            })  );
>     }
> ```

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the following?

```
  o.Customers != null ?   o.Customers.ShortName  : ""
```